# Append text with styling

Tags: css, reactjs

I was wondering how to merge 2 pieces of text together in React JS. Difference is 1 section of the text has its own unique styling. Example code below:

```
<div>
    <div>
      {'If you haven\'t recieved an email, please check your spam filter or '}
    </div>
    <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>
      try another email address
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using `flex` and `flex direction` as `row` in the parent div, but have had no luck. This is what happens with `flex` in the parent div.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use span (instead of div).

The span tag is an inline container used to mark up a part of a text and it doesn't break to the next line

```
<div>
  <span>
    {'If you haven\'t recieved an email, please check your spam filter or '}
  </span>
  <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>
    try another email address
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: see update to question, the `flex` does not seem to work

Comment: perfect - span worked. Thank you :D